# In each of the following, find conditions on $a$ and $b$ such that the system has no solution, one solution, and infinitely many solutions.

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-linear-algebra

Here are the given equations:

$x-by=-1$

$x+ay=3$

The augmented matrix would be :

\begin{bmatrix}
        1 & -b & -1 \\
        1 & a & 3 \\
        \end{bmatrix} 
    To which I did $(R2-R1)$:
\begin{bmatrix}
    1 & -b & -1 \\
    0 & a+b & 3 \\
    \end{bmatrix}

I'm stuck now on what I should do. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

P.S. Feel free to fix any of my symbols, I'm not great with coding.

Answer (score 0):

$$D=det\begin{bmatrix}
        1 & -b \\
        1 & a  \\
        \end{bmatrix}  = a+b$$

$$D_x=det\begin{bmatrix}
        -1 & -b \\
        3& a  \\
        \end{bmatrix}  = -a+3b$$

$$D_y=det\begin{bmatrix}
        1 & -1 \\
        1&  3 \\
        \end{bmatrix}  = 3+1=4$$

If $D=0$ (this is when $a=-b$) then we have no solution, since $D_y \ne 0$.

If $D\ne 0$ we have exactly one solution.

$$ x = {D_x\over D} = {-a+3b\over a+b}$$and $$ y = {D_y\over D} = {4\over a+b}$$

Answer (score 0):

multiplying the first equation by $-1$ and adding both we get
$$y(a+b)=4$$ if $$a+b=0$$ then we get $$0=4$$ so no Solutions, for $$a+b\ne 0$$ we get
$$y=\frac{4}{a+b}$$ and $$x=\frac{3b-a}{a+b}$$